# how to solve the problem with indexing and sorting

Tags: c++, indexing, text

I have a problem.There is a text file, you need to find 5 frequently occurring words. The program receives the file name.  Output: top 5 words in alphabetical order. The problem is that indexes are not updated and sorted crookedly. Help me please.  thanks in advance.
This is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100000;
string words[MAX];
int instances[MAX];
int cast = 0 ;

void insert (string input)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < cast; i++ )
    {
        if (input == words[i] )
        {
            instances[i]++;
            return ;
        }
    }
    if (cast < MAX)
    {
        words [cast] = input ;
        instances[cast] = 1;
        cast ++;
    }
    else
    {
        return ;
    }
 return ;
}
int FindTop (string & word)
{
    int TopCast = instances[0];
    int TopIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<cast; i++ )
    {
        if(instances[i] > TopCast )
        {
            TopCast = instances[i];
            TopIndex = i;
        }
    }
    instances[TopIndex] = 0;
    word = words[TopIndex ];
    return TopCast;
}
int main ()
{
    string word;
    string file;
    cin>>file;
    ifstream data (file);
    while(data >> word)
    {
        insert(word);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        cout<<FindTop(word)<<" "<<word<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: C++ does not guarantee the ordering of arguments in your last line. Either make the call to `FindTop` up front, or have it return a `std::pair<std::string, int>`.

Comment: @Clonk See the `ifstream data (file);` line?

Comment: @Shawn Oh yeah i must be blind this morning. Also, I suggest using data structure such as `std::map` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your FindTop() function as follows

```
        int FindTop (string & word)
        {
            int TopCast = instances[0];
            int TopIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i<cast; i++ )
            {
                if(instances[i] > TopCast )
                {
                    TopCast = instances[i];
                    TopIndex = i;
                }    
                else if(TopCast == instances[i])  
                {
                     //for making sure you get the smallest word (asc order) first if multiple words   
                     // have same frequency
                    if( words[TopIndex].compare(words[i]) > 0 )
                    {
                      TopCast = instances[i];
                      TopIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            instances[TopIndex] = 0;
            word = words[TopIndex ];
            return TopCast;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The insert function works as intended. However, if the demand really is the top 5 words, according to occurrence, sorted in alphabetical order, you might want to save the words in a vector and sort it alphabetically using a self-made string compare function.

If somehow you are not getting the top 5 words, check if your text file is in the correct directory and if you write the correct file name to the console.

Please provide a short text file and the console output.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide an additional solution.

This is not based on your initial draft, but with a more modern-C++ solution, using STL containers and algorithms.

I would strongly recommend to NOT use C-Style arrays at all. Please use STL containers.

Then, back to your problem. We will split the problem basically into 3 tasks.

- Read file
- Count words
- Sort

Reading the file into words is ultra simple. Just use the extractor operator and get the words as `std:string` out of the text. The words may contain non alpha characters. This we will eliminate with a `std::regex_replace`.

Counting is also very simple. We use the `std::map`s index operator[]. This will create a word in the `std::map` if it is not yet existing```` and increment the counter. If the word is already existing, then there will be simply an incrementation of the counter for this word.

Because the `std::map` is per default sorted by the key vale (the word), we copy the word counts to a `std::vector`, then sort it and show the result.

Please see

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

std::istringstream sourceFile{R"(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet.)"
};


int main() {

    std::string word{};
    std::map<std::string, size_t> counter;

    // Read complete file into words
    while(sourceFile >> word) {
        // Replace special characters
        word = std::regex_replace(word,std::regex(R"([\.\,\;\:\!\?])"),"");
        // Count the occurence of each word
        counter[word]++;
    }

    // We need to sort and will copy the word-counts into a vector
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, std::string>> countedWords;
    for( auto const& [key, val] : counter ) {
        countedWords.emplace_back(std::pair<size_t, std::string>(val,key));
    }

    // Do the sort, with a lambda, for the specific request
    std::sort(countedWords.begin(), countedWords.end(), 
         [](std::pair<size_t, std::string> &l, std::pair<size_t, std::string> &r){
        return ((r.first == l.first) ? (l.second < r.second) : (r.first < l.first));});



    // Show result on screen
    int outputCounter{ 5 };
    for (const auto& [word, count] : countedWords) {
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << word << " --> " << count << "\n";
        if (0 >= --outputCounter) break;
    }

    // Output all words
    std::cout << "\n\nAll different word in alphabetical order:\n\n";

    // Write all words on screen.
    for (const auto& [word, count] : counter)   std::cout << word << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I added at the end the output for all words in alphabetical order.

Additionally: Please note: `std::istringstream` is a `std::istream`. There is no difference to a file stream. So "sourceFile" can be an open `std::ifstream` or `std::cin` or any other `std::istream`. There is no difference. So open a file using `std::ifstream sourceFile("c:\\temp\nameOfFile")`- That's it.

Comment: okey, but what if we need to output the words in alphabetical order and the register is not important to us ? (and please can you still add text file input in your example? I'm just a beginner in programming)

Comment: @George: I modified my post. Please look at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is more like C-ish I would like to show you my take on the problem.

I highly encourage you to take a look at the various [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (especially [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) and on the [algorithm library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). With just these you will end up with a much cleaner and less error-prone code.

```
#include <algorithm> // sort
#include <cstdlib> // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <fstream> // ifstream
#include <iostream> // cin, cout
#include <string> // string
#include <unordered_map> // unordered_map
#include <utility> // pair
#include <vector> // vector

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Filename: ";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;

    ifstream file{filename};
    // Check that the file was opened successfully.
    if (!file) {
        cout << "File cannot be opened for reading: " << filename << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Count the words in the file.
    // unordered_map is an associative container that stores key-value pairs
    // with unique keys. We use this to store word-occurrence pairs.
    unordered_map<string, int> words;
    for (string word; file >> word;)
        // By default if 'word' is not contained in 'words' it will be placed
        // there with the default value of 0 (default value of ints). This allow
        // us the eliminate the special case when 'word' is not in 'words' yet.
        ++words[word];

    // Sort the word-occurrence pairs in descending order by occurrence.
    // vector is a dynamic array that we use to sort the word-occurrence pairs
    // because unordered_map cannot be sorted.
    vector<std::pair<string, int>> sorted_words{words.begin(), words.end()};
    // The sort algorithm takes the begining and the end of the interval that we
    // want to sort. As a third argument we pass it a lamda function that tells
    // the algorithm how to order our word-occurrence pairs.
    sort(sorted_words.begin(), sorted_words.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return a.second > b.second;
    });
    // Sort the first 5 (most frequent) words in alphabetic order.
    sort(sorted_words.begin(), sorted_words.begin() + 5, [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return a.first < b.first;
    });

    for (auto i = 0; i < 5 && i < sorted_words.size(); ++i)
        cout << sorted_words[i].first << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```